how can i add a javascript function that changes the colour of all backgrounds and color schemes on all html pages for my website?
how can I add a Javascript function that changes the colour of all backgrounds and color schemes on all html pages for my website?
tried function but only changed the background of one page. what do i do??? really struggling here

It's hard to tell without seeing your code but it sounds like you are currently not storing the modified background color value so it is lost when navigating to a different page. Look into Web Storage API for ways to store your selected color value and apply it when loading a page.

Not really clear what you are actually trying to do. Do you want to go through your static html on the backend and change the existing html files? Do you want to include a function in your html that is executed on the frontend when the browser loads your file? Wouldn't using some CSS be simpler and more intuitive than using JS to tamper with your styling?


I'd say if you're using plain HTML vanilla JS or JQuery, you can add the function you used in a script tag on all the pages of your site.


Also using vanilla JS you can include the background colour in window.localStorage and access it across multiple pages but you'd still need a script for that anyway


If you're using a framework like React you can include it as a layout wrapper so the function is always called on all the pages you want it on.

The function looks like this and could also work in any JS framework as well:
document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundColor = '#fff';

I'd need more details to help with what you're trying to achieve though.
